# the function fancybox.open() 's parameters callback function made it didn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, fancybox

How can I use this callback function?

i had to use `fancybox.open()` in a function ,the code like this:

```
enter code here:
  $.fancybox.open([{href :'#up_price_box'}],{
          beforeLoad: function(){/**/},
          afterLoad: function(){
            var apointment_id =obj.find("input[name='appointment_id']").val();
            **myprice_count=setInterval(get_doctor_message,10000);**
          },
          afterClose :function(){
            clearInterval(myprice_count);
        }
  });
```

`get_doctor_message` is a function

```
myprice_count=setInterval(get_doctor_message,10000,apointment_id,obj);
```

it's this code made the function didn't work,

```
afterLoad: function(){ 
    var apointment_id =obj.find("input[name='appointment_id']").val();  
    myprice_count=setInterval(get_doctor_message,10000); 
},
```

Who can help me,and thanks a lot!

```
enter code here<div id='up_price_box'style="display:none">/**/</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working? `get_doctor_message` is not getting called?

Comment: afterLoad: function(){
            var apointment_id =obj.find("input[name='appointment_id']").val();
            **myprice_count=setInterval(get_doctor_message,10000);**
          },//can't use setInterval(),if i delete this ,the fancybox will display.

Comment: not work means the hidden box just Flashed.i want the hidden box displayed

Comment: @user2990320 : could you show the html for `#up_price_box`?

Comment: it's the hidden box .when i trigger the function fancybox,the hidden box will display.

Comment: and thank you,you are a nice man!

Comment: @user2990320 : what I meant is if you can post the code of that (hidden) html  ;)